# Selenium XPath for a table

Tags: selenium-rc

Given this html segment:

```
<strong style="background-color: transparent;">53°F</strong>
```

How to retrieve the 53°F text? I tried

```
sel.getText("//parent_selector/**strong[text()**]"))
```

but this is not working.

Comment: You need to show more of your XML. The XPath must be wrong somewhere. For example, does the `table` element really have a `class` attribute with that value?

Comment: Dabbler's right, you need to show the surrounding HTML.  Also, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: Assuming you're scraping The Weather Channel's pages, the "°" is actually an HTML entity: `&deg;`, which is what you'll get back.  And that XPath looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :)

```
selenium.getText("xpath=//table[@class='twc-forecast-table twc-second']//tr[4]//strong");
```